# How to call method from jobject wallpaperManager using JNI?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I would like to get the wallpaper from android using c++ so I need to call wallpaperManager.getDrawable(). Supposing I have this code in java:

```
WallpaperManager.getInstance(activity).getDrawable()
final Drawable wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
```

I made this code:

```
static jmethodID Method = FJavaWrapper::FindMethod(Env, FJavaWrapper::GameActivityClassID, "getInstance", "(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/app/WallpaperManager;", false);

static jobject wallpaperManager= FJavaWrapper::CallObjectMethod(Env, FAndroidApplication::GetGameActivityThis(), Method);
```

How do I call getDrawable() or peekDrawable() ?

Update:

When I try to call:

```
auto awmclass = NewScopedJavaObject(JEnv, JEnv->FindClass("android/app/WallpaperManager"));    
jmethodID getInstanceMethod = JEnv->GetStaticMethodID(*awmclass, "getInstance", "(Landroid/content/Context;)Landroid/app/WallpaperManager;");
auto WallpaperManager = NewScopedJavaObject(JEnv, JEnv->CallStaticObjectMethod(*awmclass, getInstanceMethod, nullptr));
jmethodID peekDrawableMethod = JEnv->GetMethodID(JEnv->FindClass("android/app/WallpaperManager"), "peekDrawable", "()Landroid/app/WallpaperManager;");
jobject javaDrawable = JEnv->CallObjectMethod(*WallpaperManager, peekDrawableMethod, nullptr);
```

I get this error:
`Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference at android.app.WallpaperManager android.app.WallpaperManager.getInstance(android.content.Context) in call to FindClass`

Comment: Your code already demonstrates that you know how to locate jmethodIDs and call object methods, so what is stopping you? Note that mixing JNI code with `static` is a terrible idea.

Comment: Should I use "getInstance.getDrawable" ? I have to mention that I don't have any method declared in java, I want to call them from android.

Comment: In Plain JNI you would 1) call `GetObjectClass` on `wallpaperManager` 2) use that to `FindMethod` the `getDrawable` method and 3) call the method on `wallpaperManager` with `CallObjectMethod`. You seem to be using wrappers from Unreal engine, which I have no experiene with.

Comment: I will try and I will come back with an answer. Thankyou very much

Comment: I am stuck with this. After call CallObjectMethod I should call GetObjectField ? but what type of object is Drawable ? Is this type int and how to convert it to a c++ object afterwards ?

Comment: Edit your question with what you have. Why do you think you need GetObjectfield? `getDrawable` is a method...

Comment: getDrawable returns a Drawable object from the doc so you say I don't need to GetObjectField, right ? How do I use it in c++ ? I thought of converting to raw data or use `const void* outPixels = JEnv->GetDirectBufferAddress(buffer);`

Comment: Drawables are not necessarily bitmaps. You may have to draw it to an in-memory canvas first and grab a bitmap from there. I suggest you work out how to do this in plain Java or Kotlin first.

Comment: In Java you can convert the Drawable in a Bitmap, if I do convert it the question remains how to use it in c++.

Comment: ... by reproducing the series of Java method calls into JNI calls. It is always the same pattern: GetObjectClass, FindMethod, CallObjectMethod.

Comment: Is it ok the signature cause it doesn't find the method ? `FindMethod(JEnv, wmclass, "getDrawable", "()V", false)`

Comment: I think it's deprecated, now it's peekDrawable

Comment: It crashes saying : can't call android.graphics.drawable.Drawable android.app.WallpaperManager.peekDrawable() on instance of java.lang.Class<android.app.WallpaperManager> `jmethodID Method = FJavaWrapper::FindMethod(JEnv, wmclass, "peekDrawable", "()Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;", true)`

Comment: It's an object method, not a static method. Call it on `wallpaperManager` instead of `wmclass`

Comment: So the problem was that I didn't set the context right. @Botje you helped me in the right direction so please write an answer so I can mark this as solved. Thankyou!